# Error with 'import xlwt' and 'import xlrd' in Python 2.7 after installation with anaconda

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, xlrd, xlwt

I want to create xls and for that I installed `xlwt` and `xlrd` modules with `easy_install xlwt`.

But every installation, is related to `C:\Anaconda` and not to `C:\python27`. Maybe thats why:

```css
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import xlwt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import xlwt
ImportError: No module named xlwt
>>>
```

How can I install in `C:python27`? Or isn't it the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda is first on your PATH, so when you run `easy_install` it uses the one in the Anaconda directory. If you use the one in the C:\Python27 directory it will install it there.